# Android Studio new project shows Runtime exception error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just downloaded the Android Studio v0.8.0. I have installed Android 4.4 APIs . When i create a new project and run it on emulator, It shows Unfortunately  has been stopped. Any help will be very much remembered as I'm new to Android Studio with little experience from ADT eclipse.

**P.S** I have configured the SDK path and JDK paths.

I have attached the screenshots of error log, emulator, logcat as requested.

[image: Error Logs![][1]]

[image: Emulator]

[image: Logcat]

Comment: Increase the emulator RAM memory...

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy and pasted the full RunTimeException into your answer.

Comment: Increasing the emulator RAM memory did not work out

Comment: Please copy and paste the error here. The screenshots are too small on my screen to read.

Comment: The Runtime exception errors are too big to be pasted as comment.

Comment: 07-22 17:15:59.958    1698-1698/naren.example.com.abc D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-22 17:15:59.968    1698-1698/naren.example.com.abc W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0dc1ce8)
07-22 17:15:59.998    1698-1698/naren.example.com.abc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: naren.example.com.abc, PID: 1698,  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{naren.example.com.abc/naren.example.com.abc.MyActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar

Comment: Went back to API level 19 , changed the TargetSDKversion to 19 , It worked . Thanks a bunch guys